# Groovy Binding SignatureParser Error

Tags: groovy

I can't create an instance of the groovy.lang.Binding class.

Simplest reproduction:

```
package com.ajilius.test;
import groovy.lang.Binding;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Binding binding = new Binding();
    }
}
```

Error when running this code in Netbeans' debugger:

```
Listening on 51995
User program running
Exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("18") breakpoint hit in sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser at line 95 by thread main.
Thread main stopped at SignatureParser.java:95.
User program finished
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Output from groovy -version:

```
Groovy Version: 2.4.6 JVM: 1.8.0_60 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X
```

Comment: Have you tried running it without the debugger?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've just tried running the code without debugging, and it appeared to work successfully. I also ran the more complex code that first raised the problem, and it appeared to work as well. It doesn't solve the broader problem, yet, because I still need to be able to run the application under the debugger during development.

Comment: But then it seems you have problems not with your code, but with your debugger.  Should be a separate question then.

Answer (score 0):

Nikem's response led to the answer.

A breakpoint on ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException had been left in the debugger.